# Python Ctypes weird behavior

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to design a bot for an application called Virtual Paradise and the SDK that is given for building the bot is compiled into a shared library, therefore I have to use ctypes.

when I use

```
import threading
...
from ctypes import CDLL, CFUNCTYPE, c_char_p, c_int, c_void_p
vp = CDLL("libvpsdk.so")
vp.vp_string.restype = c_char_p
vp.vp_int.restype = c_int
...
class bot(threading.Thread):
    def initBot(self):
        ...
        instance = vp.vp_create()
        ...
        EventFunc = CFUNCTYPE(None)
        event_chat_func = EventFunc(self.event_chat)
        vp.vp_event_set(instance, 0, event_chat_func)
        ...
    def event_chat(self):
        print "Hello"
        ...
```

event_chat gets called correctly and prints "Hello"

but when I use this

```
import threading
import chat
...
from ctypes import CDLL, CFUNCTYPE, c_char_p, c_int, c_void_p
vp = CDLL("libvpsdk.so")
vp.vp_string.restype = c_char_p
vp.vp_int.restype = c_int
...
class bot(threading.Thread):
    def initBot(self):
        ...
        instance = vp.vp_create()
        ...
        chat.VPSDK(vp, instance)
        ...
```

Chat.py:

```
from ctypes import CFUNCTYPE
...
class VPSDK:
    def __init__(self, vp, instance):
        EventFunc = CFUNCTYPE(None)
        event_chat_func = EventFunc(self.event_chat)
        vp.vp_event_set(instance, 0, event_chat_func)

    def event_chat(self):
        print "Hello"
        ...
```

I get the error "Illegal instruction"

What am I doing wrong!? I need to use this separate class, otherwise other parts of my bot will loose functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must maintain a reference to the wrapped function for the lifetime it may be called.  See the **Important note...** at the end of [15.16.1.17. Callback functions](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) in the [Python ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes).

One way is to use `self.event_chat_func` instead, storing it for the lifetime of the containing object.

Also, creating `chat.VPSDK(vp, instance)` creates an instance of `chat.VPSDK` that goes out of scope in the next line.  You don't demonstrate how `bot` is instantiated in the first example, but the `VPSDK` object doesn't live very long.

Comment: Thanks, I just made the variable "event_chat_func" global within "chat.py" and now it works without any problems.